# Gold amount in minute 10 in league of legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering how much gold would Zed get if he farms every minion in mid-lane for 10 minutes and without dying or killing any champion? (Includes the free gold income)I would just like to know the approximate gold count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`starting gold:  500`

`Minions: 20(per minion)*101(total in 10 mins) + 5*20(cannon bonus)`

`idle gold: 20.4(per 10s) * 6(10*6 = minute) * 8(10-2 total duration)`

total: 3600

sources: https://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/comments/451dpw/perfect_cs_chart_updated_for_season_6/

Comment: Can you please tell me what do the numbers refer to?

Comment: edited my answer.